# How do you form this term correctly (looks like binomial formula just with logic operations)?

Tags: calculus, logic, propositional-calculus, predicate-logic

Here is a simple example and I'm pretty sure that I formed it correctly:

$$(A \wedge A) \vee (\bar{A} \wedge B) = (A \vee \bar{A}) \wedge (A \vee B) = 1 \wedge (A \vee B) = (A \vee B)$$

But what about this one:

$$(A \wedge \bar{B} \wedge \bar{C}) \vee (\bar{A} \wedge B \wedge \bar{C}) \vee (\bar{A} \wedge \bar{B} \wedge C) \vee (A \wedge B \wedge C)$$

I have no idea where to start but I started by sort the variables:

$$(A \vee \bar{A} \vee \bar{A} \vee A) \wedge (\bar{B} \vee B \vee \bar{B} \vee B) \wedge (\bar{C} \vee \bar{C} \vee C \vee C)=$$

$$(A \vee \bar{A}) \wedge (\bar{B} \vee B) \wedge (\bar{C} \vee C) = 1 \wedge 1 \wedge 1 = 1$$

I can see it's totally wrong, I know it.. But how to do that correctly?

What I'm trying to do here actually is minimizing the complete term.

Here I made table but how can you read the shorter function from it and use XOR?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What makes you think you can sort the letters?

The formula you are looking at is true if all three variables are true, or if precisely one variable is true. Thus, if you use $\otimes$ to describe the "exclusive or" operation, your formula is equivalent to
$$
A \otimes B \otimes C.
$$
If you are limited to $\lor, \land, \neg$ I do not think there is a much shorter way to write the formula than what you wrote.

Comment: Can you please show how you got to this XOR result?

Comment: By making the truth table for both my expression and the one you are working with. (Actually, I didn't really *make* the truth table this time around, I just recalled it from memory.)

Comment: I will make a table now and upload, can you please help after? What to do on table.

Comment: Ok I added table hope it becomes clear now for me when you tell.

Comment: @cnmesr, that is not a full truth table, that is just the part of the truth table where your expression is true. By giving the full truth table, and the full truth table for *my* expression, you can see that the two expressions are equal.

Comment: Is the table complete now?

Comment: @cnmesr, no, you still need all the rows where two out of $A,B,C$ are true. You just need all possible combinations for true/false for the three values $A,B,C$.

Comment: Now is fine...? :D But how read XOR now? Can I compare each line and if there is for example 0 and 1 after, I can erase both because both are opposite? Or what's the trick to get your formula? Thank you very much for talking by the way and help.

Comment: It is *still* not complete; also, the values in the $X$ column are wrong. Do you know what "exclusive or" means?

Comment: Ok this is very frustrating.. : / I don't